# Error while trying to open new Emacs.app after upgrade to Yosemite

Tags: terminal, upgrade, homebrew, macos, emacs

After upgrade to Yosemite I get this when trying to launch new Emacs app from command-line. I've spent yesterday trying to figure out what's the problem, so today I decided to ask here.

```
➜  ~  open -n -a Emacs
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.3/Emacs.app with error -10810.
```

Edit: might be helpful, info from /var/log/system.log:

```
Oct 20 16:02:49 Kostiantyns-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system): Caller not allowed to perform action: open.2674, action = service submission, code = 1: Operation not permitted, uid = 501, euid = 501, gid = 20, egid = 20, asid = 100005
Oct 20 16:02:49 Kostiantyns-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system): Caller not allowed to perform action: open.2674, action = legacy spawn, code = 1: Operation not permitted, uid = 501, euid = 501, gid = 20, egid = 20, asid = 100005
Oct 20 16:02:49 Kostiantyns-MacBook-Pro.local open[2674]: spawn_via_launchd() failed, errno=1 label=[0x0-0xbf0bf].org.gnu.Emacs path=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs flags=0 : LaunchApplicationClient.cp #963 LaunchApplicationWithSpawnViaLaunchD() q=com.apple.main-thread
Oct 20 16:02:49 Kostiantyns-MacBook-Pro.local open[2674]: spawn_via_launchd() failed, errno=1 label=[0x0-0xbf0bf].org.gnu.Emacs path=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs flags=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't know what exactly happened, turns out if you won't launch this from tmux -- you'll be just fine.

// thanks https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/3093

Comment: Bizarre...but you saved me a lot of time as ran into this exact problem involving launchctl. After seeing your answer I googled around a bit and found [this discussion](https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=997) which seems to suggest it's a longstanding conflict between tmux and launchctl.